# How to escape all special characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using the D3 library. I want to programatically select an element by its ID, but that ID includes a comma. I am reading the IDs in as part of the data, so I can't control that.

My code is:

```
g.nodes().forEach(function(v) {
   d3.select('#'+v+)
   .attr("cx", function(){return g.node(v).x; })
   .attr("cy", function(){return g.node(v).y; })
});
```

Where v is a string that matches the ID.

Specifically, when I try `d3.select("#B_ne_,3")` I get `d3.js:562 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'querySelector' on 'Document': '#B_ne_,3' is not a valid selector.(…)`.

I know that I can select it by using `"#B_ne_\\,3"`, but how can I escape these characters in general?

I am NOT using jquery.

Comment: var x =encodeURIComponent("#B_ne_,3");d3.select(x);

Comment: The [*cssesc*](https://github.com/mathiasbynens/cssesc) library should be able to do the job. It comes with an in-depth explanation of [CSS character escape sequences](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/css-escapes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`CSS.escape`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS/escape) (experimental as of May 2017):

```js
var v = "B_ne_,3";
console.log("#" + CSS.escape(v));
```

There are exact polyfills for old browser, but it's simpler if you escape unnecessary characters:

```js
var v = "B_ne_,3";
console.log("#" + v.replace(/\W/g, '\\$&').replace(/^\d/, '\\00003$&'));
```